# Please allow more characters in suggested edit custom reject reason

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

150 characters seems like quite a lot on the face of it, but I've repeatedly exceeded this limit when explaining to a user why I'm rejecting their edit.

For instance, on [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/289478), I was hoping to write:

> Please don't add hi/thanks/salutations; see meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2950/16386, but even then I'd have rejected this as "Too minor: suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post."

*Yes* I could have shortened it to:

> See meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2950/163863, but even then I'd have rejected it as too minor.

**But we shouldn't be held back from teaching/helping users because of a basic character limit.** (and this is just an example... there *have* been situations where I've had to omit useful information to the user *just* to go below 150 chars).

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, Please.

Having your proposed edit rejected is never nice. Especially when you're really trying to improve a certain post, and you get the edit rejected without a clear explanation.

For this reason, I very often choose to use the *custom reject reason* to explain why I rejected the edit. I think that it is very important to explain why I think that the edit was bad, so that the proposer understands the rejection. And, to be honest, 150 characters is never enough to make myself clear, and add as many details as I'd like to.

**Allowing more characters in the custom reject tab seems fairly easy to implement, and it can only lead to a better experience for everyone.**