# Allow hyperlinks in custom reject reasons

Tags: feature-request, rejection-reasons

I recently discussed an edit in chat, after which I decided to reject it. I then added a link to that discussion (to avoid repeating stuff, which itself would not have worked too well considering [the character limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136184)). Sadly, I later found the link unclickable.

Comment: Probably not much point, no one reads those anyway. The real feature request to support is the one where we show people in an obvious way why their edits were rejected so they can learn and improve.

Comment: *no one* is too strong a claim

Comment: Yes, it's strong, but unfortunately true. I personally read my flag rejections, but I can't assume that everyone does, as it isn't obvious where they lie. It's the same basic deal with edits. Unless you really care, you won't check.